How to enhance images like Topaz's Gigapixel AI?
I would like to see if WL is up to the task of industrial strength image enhancement e.g. Topaz Lab's Photo AI product. I'm sure with all the neural network APIs available now, someone would have an idea of how to achieve some quality semantic image upscaling results.
Here's a side-by-side comparison from Topaz (processed output on the right):

And a zoomed-in version:


One question is whether you might actually want to do that. These sorts of things are usually effectively a "best guess" of what an image "should" be like, meaning that that guess often includes information that is not actually there. E.g. you can see how what is probably a more scaled, pebbly pattern on the underside of the jaw is "guessed" to have more straight lines, like folds of skin, how one of the fingers gets strangely fringed, and so forth. And that's what we can see without a high-resolution closeup of the image, which would probably reveal a lot more.

We can use the "Enhanced Super-Resolution GAN Trained on DIV2K, Flickr2K and OST Data" NetModel, although the performance doesn't seem to match Topaz here.
(There is also this from the function repo which uses the same NN as one of its choosable Methods but it kept eating all my memory when I tried to call it).
Note that this is really just a copy-paste of the documentation example for the NN above. I don't want to seem like I'm taking credit for this example, because I changed very little compared to the documentation example, other than supplying your lizard image.
I use a zoom factor of 4. Note that the evaluation function emphasizes "Speed" over "Quality" for zoom factors greater than 4. It also uses CPU instead of GPU (I am unsure whether GPU is supported as a TargetDevice for this GAN). This evaluation function is directly pulled from the net model's documentation:
Options[netevaluate] = {PerformanceGoal -> Automatic, 
   TargetDevice -> "CPU"};
netevaluate[img_, imgScale_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Block[{net, resizedNet, resizedImg, resizeScale, perfGoal, res, 
   numResizes}, perfGoal = OptionValue[PerformanceGoal];
  If[perfGoal === Automatic && imgScale <= 4, perfGoal = "Quality"];
  If[perfGoal === Automatic && imgScale > 4, perfGoal = "Speed"];
  net = NetModel[
    "Enhanced Super-Resolution GAN Trained on DIV2K, Flickr2K and OST \
Data"];
  numResizes = Ceiling[Log[4, imgScale]];
  resizeScale = imgScale/(4^numResizes);
  res = img;
  Do[resizedNet = 
    NetReplacePart[net, 
     "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", ImageDimensions@res}]];
   res = resizedNet[res, TargetDevice -> OptionValue[TargetDevice]];, 
   numResizes - 1];
  If[perfGoal == "Speed", res = ImageResize[res, Scaled[resizeScale]]];
  resizedNet = 
   NetReplacePart[net, 
    "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", ImageDimensions@res}]];
  res = resizedNet[res, TargetDevice -> OptionValue[TargetDevice]];
  If[perfGoal == "Quality", 
   res = ImageResize[res, Scaled[resizeScale]]];
  res]

Then grab the original resolution part of your image:
img = Import["https://i.sstatic.net/YJilH7x7.png"];
img = ImageTake[img, All, {1, 950}];

And downscale (to preserve image dimension), pass through the GAN, and get the ouput:
zoom = 4;
downScaled = ImageResize[img, Scaled[1/zoom]];
upScaled = netevaluate[downScaled, zoom];

We can compare the features near the lizard face of the original, the NN upscaled image, and naive upsampling:
naive = ImageResize[downScaled, Scaled[zoom]];

Grid[{{"Naive", "Net", "Original"}, 
  Table[ImageTake[
    image, {300, 500}, {400, 700}], {image, {naive, upScaled, img}}]},
  Frame -> All]


The GAN output doesn't look that much different from the original image. Let's try a higher zoom factor of 10 (note that we now have PerformanceGoal switched to Speed now):
zoom = 10;
downScaled = ImageResize[img, Scaled[1/zoom]];
upScaled = netevaluate[downScaled, zoom];
naive = ImageResize[downScaled, Scaled[zoom]];
Grid[{{"Naive", "Net", "Original"}, 
   Table[ImageTake[
     image, {300, 500}, {400, 700}], {image, {naive, upScaled, 
      img}}]}, Frame -> All]


The improvement still seems to be quite modest, and certainly nowhere near the improvement observed by using Topaz Lab's super-resolution feature.
Super-resolution might be a nice new feature for built-in Wolfram language, as it seems a lot of users want this feature now (maybe it exists somewhere and I'm just not aware of it?)
